# WPF Simple TextBox Binding - Dependency Property Never Touched

Tags: wpf, binding, textbox, dependency-properties

I have a `TextBox` and I'm trying to bind it to a `DependencyProperty`. The property is never touched on load or when I type in the `TextBox`. What am I missing?

**XAML**

```
<UserControl:Class="TestBinding.UsernameBox"
        // removed xmlns stuff here for clarity>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="23" Name="usernameTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=Username, ElementName=myWindow, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**C#**

```
public partial class UsernameBox : UserControl
{
    public UsernameBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            // Control never reaches here
            return (string)GetValue(UsernameProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            // Control never reaches here
            SetValue(UsernameProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UsernameProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register("Username", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow));
}
```

Edit: I need to implement a `DependencyProperty` because I am creating my own control.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a DependencyProperty as the source of your binding! See my answer...

Comment: Oops, I did not make that clear. I am actually creating my own control, so it needs to be a Dependency Property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You never reach setter because it is CLR wrapper of dependency property, it is declared to be set from external sources, like `mainWindow.Username = "myuserName";`. When the property is set through binding and you want to see if it changed or not just add the `PropertyMetadata` to your declaration with `PropertyChangedCallback`, for example:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty UsernameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Username", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, UsernamePropertyChangedCallback));

        private static void UsernamePropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Print("OldValue: {0}", e.OldValue);
            Debug.Print("NewValue: {0}", e.NewValue);
        }
```

With this code you will see changes of your property in Output Window of VS.

For more info on callbacks please read [Dependency Property Callbacks and Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: See also the explanation in [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx), section "Implications for Custom Dependency Properties".

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was missing something.

Comment: No ways! you should not use a DependencyProperty as the source of your binding - see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be using a `DependencyProperty` here!

Your TextBox's `Text` property is a `DependencyProperty` and is the *target* of your binding. Your Username Property is the source and should **not** be a `DependencyProperty`! Rather, it should be a plain old property that raises [NotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.100).aspx).

All you need is:

```
private string _username;
public string Username
{
    get
    {
        return _username;
    }
    set
    {
        _username = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("Username");
    }
}
```

(Aside: you only need to use DependencyProperties when you are authoring your own control.)